# Listing Types in a Column with count Selecting all types whether the column value or not

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a table for example Persons with person type(Private, Public, Government, Businessman, Jobless). Type can be null or Empty. I am saving type value in Person table with no Master Table. I want to select all grouped types with count by wheather the type exists or not.
I know it is a bit strange but the requirements are like this. Below are the scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE [Persons](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FULLNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TYPE] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


  INSERT INTO Persons(FULLNAME,[TYPE]) VALUES('ABD', 'Private');
  INSERT INTO Persons(FULLNAME,[TYPE]) VALUES('DEF', 'Government');
  INSERT INTO Persons(FULLNAME,[TYPE]) VALUES('DEF', 'Jobless');
```

The result should look like as follows:

```
TYPE                             COUNT
Private                          1
Public                           0
Government                       1
Businessman                      0
Jobless                          1
```

Comment: Please edit your post (use the edit link under the post), find the subject tags at the bottom, remove "oracle" and add whatever product you actually have (if it is not Oracle). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Common Table Expression (CTE) of all the possible types using `with` clause and left join it with the persons table.

```
with types (type)
as (
    select 'Private' from dual
    union all
    select 'Public' from dual
    union all 
    select 'Government' from dual
    union all
    select 'Businessman' from dual
    union all 
    select 'Jobless' from dual
    )
select t.type,
    count(p.type) "COUNT"
from types t
left outer join Persons p on t.type = p.type
group by t.type;
```

Comment: A CTE is not a temporary table, but otherwise your solution looks correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fixed. Ta.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnot work if I put WHERE p.FULLNAME='DEF'. Then it sows only Government and Jobless with count.

Comment: Doesn't work how? What does it produce in result? And what is expected?

Comment: `With types(type) as (select 'Private' from dual union all
Select 'Public' from dual union all
Select 'Government' from dual union all
Select 'Businessman' from dual union all
Select 'Jobless' from dual)
Select t.type, count(p.type) "COUNT" from types t left outer join
Persons p
On t.type = p.type
where p.FULLNAME='DEF'
Group by t.type`

And it shows this result

Government 1
Jobless         2

Comment: Even if has has only Government and Jobless, it should show the others too.

Comment: @AbdullahFeroz Instead of `where` use `and`

Answer (score 1):

In case you use MS Sql Server not Oracle (as syntax of your DDLs suggest):

```
  select all_types.type, count(distinct persons.id) from (
      select 'Private' as type union all
      select 'Public' union all
      select 'Government' union all
      select 'Businessman' union all 
      select 'Jobless'
      ) all_types left outer join Persons on (all_types.type=persons.type)  
      group by all_types.type;
```

Comment: Same problems. When I query as follows then only 2 Types are shown:

`select all_types.type, count(distinct persons.id) from (
      select 'Private' as type union all
      select 'Public' union all
      select 'Government' union all
      select 'Businessman' union all 
      select 'Jobless'
      ) all_types left outer join Persons on (all_types.type=persons.type)  
      WHERE Persons.FULLNAME='DEF'
   group by all_types.type`

Comment: Put your aditional condition in on ().select all_types.type, count(distinct persons.id) from ( select 'Private' as type union all select 'Public' union all select 'Government' union all select 'Businessman' union all select 'Jobless' ) all_types left outer join Persons on (all_types.type=persons.type and Persons.FULLNAME='DEF' ) WHERE group by all_types.type

Comment: Although I need it in oracle but for reference in SQL Server it also works. Perfect. Thanks